# In this code, when it is run, the first part is perfect, while the second part, when I press 2, addresses an issue. I am a new coder btw

Tags: python

This is my code. It is a part of the main code:

```
        up=input("Choose your number- ")
        c = int(up)
        if type(c)==int:
            print("The number chosen is", c)
            if c%2==0:
                print(c, "is even")
            else:
                d=c+1
                print(c, "is odd, so added one to make it even")
                print (d, "is your new number")
        else:
            print("Type a number, not a word or sentence")
```

As we know, the input is a string. Now, when I input a number, everything is fine. But when I input a letter, it obviously brings up an error. How do I tackle this issue so that it shows no issue? I have even tried float.

Comment: What do you *want* to happen if it's not an int?

Comment: With `c = int(up)`, `c` is guaranteed to be an `int`, so `if type(c) == int` will always be true…

Comment: as @deceze points out, your code will never reach the `else` statement, because whatever  the `up` input is, it will either be converted to an integer, or it will fail and return an error when `up` can not be converted to an integer.

Comment: Ya i saw that and therefore my question